# If $\nu : \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ is an elementary embedding, then is it true that $\mathbb{M} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Exactly as the title suggests:

If $\nu : \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ is an elementary embedding, then is it true that $\mathbb{M} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I am assuming that $\mathbb{M}$, $\mathbb{N}$ are the underlying sets. There is no reason for one to be a subset of the other. For an extreme example, suppose that the language has no non-logical symbols, and $\mathcal{M}$ has underlying set $\{1\}$ while $\mathcal{N}$ has underlying set $\{2\}$. Then the mapping that takes $1$ to $2$ is an elementary embeddding, but the underlying sets are disjoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elementary embedding $\nu \colon \mathcal M \to \mathcal N$ between $\mathcal L$-structures is a map $\nu\colon M\to N$ on the underlying sets such that for every $\mathcal L$-formula $\varphi(\bar x)$, one has
$$ \mathcal M \models \varphi(\bar m) \iff \mathcal N \models \varphi(\nu(\bar m)) .$$
In particular, $\nu$ is injective (prove it!). So maybe $\mathcal M$ is not a substructure of $\mathcal N$ (see André Nicolas's comment), but $\nu(\mathcal M)$ is. Of course, by $\nu(\mathcal M)$ I denote the $\mathcal L$-structure

- whose underlying set is $\nu(M)$,
- where a constant symbol $c$ has interpretation $\nu(c^\mathcal M)$,
- where a function symbol $f$ has interpretation $(n_1,\dots,n_k) \mapsto \nu\left(f^\mathcal M(\nu^{-1}(n_1),\dots,\nu^{-1}(n_k))\right)$,
- where a relation symbol $R$ has interpretation $\nu(R^\mathcal M)$.

Comment: Aside from a matter of definition, why is the function symbol interpreted as $(m_1,\ldots,m_k) \rightarrow \nu(f^{\mathcal{M}}(m_1,\ldots,m_k))$ as opposed to $\nu(m_1,\ldots,m_k) \rightarrow f^{\mathcal{N}}(\nu(m_1,\ldots,m_k))$?

Comment: @chibro2 You're absolutely right, my definition was ill-typed. I edited (it is the same as your proposal because $\nu$ is elementary, but I think the form I give enlighten more the fact that we just transport everything from $\mathcal M$).

Answer (score 3):

Not just the general answer is negative as shown by others, it is also possible to have the opposite, namely $j\colon\cal M\to N$ an elementary embedding, but $\Bbb{N\subsetneq M}$.

For example, pick an order isomorphism from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$.